# ApplicationDomain.getDefinition not working in Release Build for iOS

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air

I am loading an external SWF file and using ApplicationDomain.getdefination("Slide1") in my Flex4.6 using AIR 3.2 for iOS to get the Embed content inside it.

It works fine when I compile in Debug Mode(Fast) but gives Ref Error 1065 (See Error Line* below) on iPad when compiles in Release Mode(Standard).

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

The sample code in my actionscript class looks like :-

```
var request:URLRequest;
request = new URLRequest(strSwfPath);
var rslLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var appDom:ApplicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain( ApplicationDomain.currentDomain );
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false,appDom);
loaderContext.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;
rslLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadSwfCompleteHandler, false, 0, true);
rslLoader.load(request, loaderContext);

//--
private var loadedAppDomain:ApplicationDomain;
public var embedClass:Class;
//--

private function loadSwfCompleteHandler(event:Event):void 
{
     loadedAppDomain = rslLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain;
     embedClass = loadedAppDomain.getDefinition(slideName) as Class; // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> *Error Line.
}

//--------------------- The code inside my external SWF looks like:-
package 

{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flashx.textLayout.compose.ISWFContext;
    public class Slide1 extends Sprite implements ISWFContext  {

        [Embed("slide1/sldBg1.png", mimeType="image/png")]
        public static const bg:Class;
        public function callInContext(fn:Function, thisArg:Object, argsArray:Array, returns:Boolean=true):*{
             if (returns)
                     return fn.apply(thisArg, argsArray);
             fn.apply(thisArg, argsArray);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are issues w/ the iOS App store agreement about runtime code; so this won't work.

Adobe has a [sort of work-around](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/) that makes this work.  It was introduced in AIR 3.6; so you're going to have to upgrade your AIR SDK.

Comment: Thanks for replying , but it doesn't work either with AIR 3.6, gives me same Error on same line : Error # 1065.

Comment: I haven't run into this personally; so can't comment more.